# CM IIS 503 Error

Tags: iis

Getting a `503` on my CM site in IIS (server 2012) - I have checked all the settings for the app pool, file systems permissions, etc. Checked all the logs that I know and tried using procmon to see if I could spot something causing the issue. This was working fine and suddenly stopped working in our dev environment.

All other sites/app pools are working on this server - it's just this one site that won't start. I tried switching the CM site to an app pool that is working on another site.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked Windows Event Viewer to see what errors are reported?

Comment: Yes, the only clue I am getting from the event viewer is 'initialization error' shortly after the app pool starts up to handle a request. I also tried using logman and outputting the file to evtx, but all it shows is SSL handshake data, nothing as to why the app pool won't start

Comment: @Jordan Did you find anything missing in your host file?

Comment: @Jordan: Check the IIS logs (C://inetpub/logs/LogFiles) with the CM application ID. To get application id -> check in IIS Advanced Settings for the respective CM site

Comment: Can you please provide a little more detail e.g. does the app pool never start, or does it start but then crash when a request comes in? Are you running any custom code which could potentially trigger such an event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I did get this fixed. What we ultimately did was copy the entire CM (the whole folder structure) site from another working environment, minus the web.config, and it started working. So, no clue what killed it, but that was the fix for anyone who finds this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a wild guess... but have you introduced something into the web.config that references a module that isn't installed? I seem to recall getting this error when I added redirects into the web.config, but the redirect module wasn't there.